# (Java) Producing image by reading from a text-file filled with digits

Tags: java, image, graphics, digits

I'm a complete beginner in Java programming and I'm interested to learn more about its concepts.

Recently, I've been given an exercise which instructs me to display two versions of a picture. The picture to be displayed is provided in the form of a data file of 40,000 digits that are arranged in rows (although there is no marker between rows) and it starts from the top of the picture. So the first digit represents the top left corner of the picture and the last is the bottom right.

Basically, what the exercise wants me to construct a program that plots a dot in one of two colours for each digit. If the digit is in the range 0 to 3 the output should be one colour and for digits in the range 4 to 9 the dot should be in the other colour.

I understand I have to use arrays and also loops to perform this. I'm familiar with the fillEllipse, drawEllipse, drawRectangle and fillRectangle but this exercise is nothing I've attempted before.

Any hints on how to make this work? Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As a hint, rather than a complete solution, I would suggest looking into creating a `java.awt.image.BufferedImage`, and then set the colors of the individual pixels using the `setRGB()` method. You would then display this image using `drawImage()` on your `Graphics` object.

Comment: My institution provided me with a package which contains EasyReader and EasyGraphics. The EasyGraphics also consists of the java.awt.image.BufferedImage but I am wondering how do I write a program which first, reads the data file and secondly, when it detects digits 0 to 3, it has to perform a specific function

Answer (score 0):

All what you need is how to read the digits from the file and put it into two dimension array

check this tutorial for [how to read a file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html)

Then you have to draw each pixel on a fram or a Panel

check this [Java basic graphics tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/basic2d/index.html)

I hope this could help!

Comment: I started off like this:

`EasyReader scan = new EasyReader("picture.txt");
EasyGraphics make = new EasyGraphics();`

After that, I dunno what to do. I'm not familiar of drawing images based on digits. @Muhammad

Answer (score 0):

use Scanner to read the data like :

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("path_to_your_digits_file"));
int[][] digits= new int [200][200];
String line;
while(sc.hasNext()){//this means there is still a line to go
  line = sc.nextLine();
  //split the line and fill the array . or read char by char ,
  // i dont know how your file looks like, it's just some simple string manipulation here
  }
  int x;
  BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(200,200,BufferedImage.TYPR_INT_RGB);
  for(int i=0;i<200;i++){
    for(int j=0;i<200;j++){
    if(digits[i][j]>0 && digits[i][j]<=3){
      x=//some color code;
     }else{
         x=//some other color code;
      } //not sure about this loop , again idk the structure of your file;
      img.setRGB(i,j,x);
     }
   }
      JLabel lbl = new JLabel();
      lbl.setSize(200,200);
      ImageIcon ico=new ImageIcon(img);
      lbl.setIcone(ico);
      lbl.setVisible(true);
      JFrame frame = new Jframe();
      frame.setSize(500,500);
      frame.add(lbl);
      frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: The structure of the file is such that the numbers stretches to 40,000 in a continuous manner. I.e, it's one number, but that number consists of 40,000 digits @vlatkozelka